# Apache2 using older PHP version than what was installed

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, php, apache-httpd

I've recently updated to `PHP 5.6.10` by building it from source (Since I can't download it from the repositories, I'm still using Wheezy 7.0).  The build went perfectly and once it was installed, using the command `php -v` gave this output.

```
PHP 5.6.10 (cli) (built: Sep 18 2016 09:23:21) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

Which means everything was installed successfully.

The problem is, when running `phpinfo()` on my apache server, it says that it's still using PHP version `5.4.45`.  It's still loading the `libphp5.so` module from `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/`.  I don't know where the `libphp5.so` file was installed during my build of `PHP 5.6.10` but I've looked all over the place.  I can't figure out how to build the apache module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to this problem.

- Install apxs2 using `sudo apt-get install apache2-threaded-dev`
- When configuring the `PHP 5.6.10` source, remember to configure `--with-apxs2` like this.  `./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2`.  I had to point to the `apxs2` command in this case.
- Build it as you normally would, use `make` followed by `sudo make install`.
- Restart the `apache2` server using `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Everything should work as planned.  This is a great way to use `PHP 5.6` on debian wheezy.  Good luck to anyone else trying this.  I hope that this helps you out.